# Automating IE with Excel VBA: no typing in a site

Tags: excel, internet-explorer-9, vba

I've succeed to navigate an intranet site: buttons, tabs, dropdown menus etc...
One problem remains: typing.

I can regularly write in the fields as I usually do in navigating sites. For example, in the login page:

```
IE.document.getElementsByTagName("INPUT")(0).Value = myId
IE.document.getElementsByTagName("INPUT")(1).Value = myPassword
IE.document.getElementsByTagName("button")(0).Click
```

Unfortunally, in this case, despite the field are filled in, when I click submit the system gets this error:

"All fields must be filled in"

```
So, I've tried to complete the fields character by character, but the result is the same.


Dim HTMLdoc As HTMLDocument
Set HTMLdoc = IE.document
Dim evtKeyDown As Object
Set evtKeyDown = HTMLdoc.createEvent("keyboardevent")
evtKeyDown.initEvent "keydown", True, False
'******************************
Dim i As Long
Dim userInput As HTMLInputElement
Set userInput = HTMLdoc.getElementsByTagName("input")(0)
userInput.Value = ""
For i = 1 To Len(myId)
  userInput.Value = userInput.Value & Mid(myId, i, 1)
  userInput.dispatchEvent evtKeyDown 
  DoEvents
Next
'******************************
Dim j As Long
Dim userInput2 As HTMLInputElement
Set userInput2 = HTMLdoc.getElementsByTagName("input")(1)
userInput2.Value = ""
For j = 1 To Len(myCode)
  userInput2.Value = userInput2.Value & Mid(myPassword, j, 1)
  userInput2.dispatchEvent evtKeyDown 
  DoEvents
Next
'******************************
IE.document.getElementsByTagName("button")(0).Click
```

Maybe the event is not well initiated, or it is not the correct event to create.

Anyway, I've noticed an unusual change in the html code:

```
<tr id="access123" class="row" style="width:330px;">
input id="log" class="textbox" type="text" maxlength="18" value=""
```

When I click on the input field, the html code becomes:

```
<tr id="access123" class="row-row-over" style="width:330px;">
input id="log" class="textbox-textbox-focus" type="text" maxlength="18" value="">
```

Comment: You can only guess what kind of validation JavaScript on the page does after button has been clicked. For sure ID and password need to be entered. I assume that there are no other fields. You need to check class name of ID input box and the same for password input box. They often change when they are filled and JavaScript checks if they are filled by looking at class name, so it must be changed before button click, because assigning value with VBA does not change class. Classes changing on input field click is also pretty standard.

Comment: I have figured out in the following way: IE.document.getElementsByTagName("INPUT")(0).Focus
IE.document.getElementsByTagName("INPUT")(0).Value = myId
IE.document.getElementsByTagName("INPUT")(0).Blur

IE.document.getElementsByTagName("INPUT")(1).Focus
IE.document.getElementsByTagName("INPUT")(1).Value = myPassword
IE.document.getElementsByTagName("INPUT")(1).Blur

IE.document.getElementsByTagName("button")(0).Click